# PHP IMAP not fetching records from cpanel roundcube inbox

Tags: php, email, phpmyadmin, cpanel, roundcube

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz5TU.png)

Connection timed out when tried to fetch emails from the cpanel roundcube.
All credentials are perfect and hostname and server also working fine.

```
$hostname = '{mail.server.com:993/novalidate-cert/imap/ssl}';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$stream = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
print_r(imap_errors());
```

Can anyone help please?
Thank you

Comment: Which version of WHM / Cpanel is it? What version of TLS does your server employ?

Comment: Is this only a recent issue, was this working previously say a few days ago?

Comment: it was working 2 weeks ago

Comment: cPanel Version = 90.0 (build 17), Apache Version 2.4.46

Comment: Go into `/var/log/maillog` in your server and open this file and see if you can find why it failed to open the mailbox.

Comment: You may need to check that your security details (Port, password encryption method, connection type, TLS certificate etc.) passed via the PHP functions fit the details expacted by the mailbox .

Comment: `$hostname = '{mail.lopitech.com:995/pop3/novalidate-cert/tls}INBOX';`
its good format I guess

Comment: I've checked many examples, they use same format.

Comment: and in the log file, there is an sql table name error. but its was previously working with the same error.

Comment: You should check what your server is actually doing; yes the format looks fine, but that assumes that all the server settings are standard. Check the correct port is open. Check POP3 is enabled, check connection . Your URL looks like you're trying to connect to an non-valid TLS so you should check if that's allowed and set the port accordingly (usually 143). Read the maillog file as previously mentioned to get the reason why the connectiob failed.

Comment: You've tagged this with the phpmyadmin tag, but I don't see what this question has to do with phpMyAdmin (which is an application meant for administrators to have graphical control over managing a MySQL or MariaDB database). Am I missing something?